# jquery isotope extra spaces

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-isotope

I've been working a project using isotope and I must have changed something because it was displaying everything correctly, then I deployed it and it is adding all these extra spaces between the .article class.  I don't know what is causing this, but I'm starting to pull my hair out because I can't see how to fix this.  There are no elements between the articles in the container, but I am using twitter bootstrap and I'm wondering if the grid could be causing that or something?  Below is the rendered page code (there's a lot) but the articles div is what I call isotope on.

here is an example of the spacing issue:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/3yw9r.jpg]

**EDIT**

I removed a lot of the HTML to focus on the isotope container div.  THANKS!
page:

**EDIT 2**

added isotope code:

I call it with these three at the bottom of my page:

```
//isotope
$("#articles").imagesLoaded(IsotopeLoad);
$(".sorter").click(IsotopeSort);

//isotope filtering
$("#filterBtns").children().click(OnFilterChange);
```

then here are those functions

```
function IsotopeLoad() {
    $("#articles").isotope({
        itemSelector: ".article",
        getSortData: {
            worn: function ($e) {
                return $e.find(".lastWornOn").text();
            },
            purchased: function ($e) {
                return $e.find(".purchasedOn").text();
            }
        }
    });
}

function IsotopeSort() {
    var sortByCode = $(this).parent().find(".sortBy").text();
        var IsAsc = $(this).parent().find(".asc").text();
        $("#articles").isotope({
            sortBy: sortByCode,
            sortAscending: IsAsc
        });
}

function OnFilterChange() {
    //check if first button is active
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }

    //get filter buttons
    var filters = $("#filterBtns").children(".active");
    var filterString = "";
    //loop through buttons to get filter values in one string
    $(filters).each(function (index, e) {
        filterString = filterString + $(e).val() + ", ";
    });

    if (filterString.substring(filterString.length - 2) == ", ") {
        filterString = filterString.substring(0, filterString.length - 2);
    }

    filterString = $.trim(filterString)
    //apply isotope
    $("#articles").isotope({
        filter: filterString
    });

}
```

page code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">

                <div class="span2">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <a class="btn btn-small dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Sort <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="sorter" id="byLastWornDesc">By Last Worn</a><span class="sortBy">worn</span><span class="asc">false</span></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sorter" id="byLastWornAsc">By First Worn</a><span class="sortBy">worn</span><span class="asc">true</span></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sorter" id="byPurchasedDesc">By Last Purchased</a><span class="sortBy">purchased</span><span class="asc">false</span></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sorter" id="byPurchasedAsc">By First Purchased</a><span class="sortBy">purchased</span><span class="asc">true</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical" id="filterBtns">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini" value=".BCBG">BCBG</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-mini" value=".Bebe">Bebe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span10">
    <div id="articles" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 750px;" class="isotope">
            <div class="article Dress Sequin Black isotope-item" id="1" rel="tooltip" data-title="Dress Sequin Black" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
                <img alt="1" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/Black%20and%20sequin%20mini%20dress.jjpgthumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn"></span> <span class="hide lastWornOn"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Sweater Tan isotope-item" id="2" rel="tooltip" data-title="Sweater Tan" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(161px, 0px, 0px);">
                <img alt="2" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/bcbg.imageg.net120212114525152thumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">11/20/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">11/29/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Leggings Black isotope-item" id="4" rel="tooltip" data-title="Leggings Black" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(483px, 0px, 0px);">
                <img alt="4" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/bcbg.imageg.net120212115347827thumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">11/21/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">12/2/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Blue Sweater isotope-item" id="5" rel="tooltip" data-title="Blue Sweater" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(805px, 0px, 0px);">
                <img alt="5" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/bcbg.imageg.net120212115533282thumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">12/1/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">12/1/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Untagged isotope-item" id="6" rel="tooltip" data-title="Untagged" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(1127px, 0px, 0px);">
                <img alt="6" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/Black%20and%20Tan%20dressthumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">12/2/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">12/2/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Untagged isotope-item" id="7" rel="tooltip" data-title="Untagged" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 250px, 0px);">
                <img alt="7" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/Black%20and%20Tan%20lace%20dressthumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn"></span> <span class="hide lastWornOn"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Black Lace Romper isotope-item" id="8" rel="tooltip" data-title="Black Lace Romper" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(322px, 250px, 0px);">
                <img alt="8" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/Black%20and%20Tan%20romperthumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">11/29/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="article White isotope-item" id="10" rel="tooltip" data-title="White" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(644px, 250px, 0px);">
                <img alt="10" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/bcbg.imageg.net120212120238879thumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">11/22/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Dress Green Sequin isotope-item" id="12" rel="tooltip" data-title="Dress Green Sequin" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(966px, 250px, 0px);">
                <img alt="12" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/DSC_0002athumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn">12/1/2012 12:00:00 AM</span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">9/24/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Black Gunmetal Metallic isotope-item" id="14" rel="tooltip" data-title="Black Gunmetal Metallic" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(1127px, 250px, 0px);">
                <img alt="14" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/EMP1thumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn"></span> <span class="hide lastWornOn"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Floral Blue Shirt isotope-item" id="15" rel="tooltip" data-title="Floral Blue Shirt" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 500px, 0px);">
                <img alt="15" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/DSC_0309athumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn"></span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">9/5/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article White Pants Stripe isotope-item" id="16" rel="tooltip" data-title="White Pants Stripe" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(322px, 500px, 0px);">
                <img alt="16" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/DSC_0430athumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn"></span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">9/1/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
            <div class="article Red Romper isotope-item" id="17" rel="tooltip" data-title="Red Romper" data-original-title="" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; -webkit-transform: translate3d(644px, 500px, 0px);">
                <img alt="17" src="http://e3da8dc1c3cfdf394995-184e01705dd318c162d0284c163588ca.r86.cf1.rackcdn.com/DSC_0055athumb.jpg">
                <span class="hide purchasedOn"></span> <span class="hide lastWornOn">7/3/2012 12:00:00 AM</span>
            </div>
    </div>
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrtOS.jpg
```

Comment: Heard of version control? I don't know anyone who would be willing to trawl through all that code...

Comment: Yeah, i figured.  Well, I'm doing this as a quick one, but I really appreciate the condescending comment.

Comment: If you post the javascript for isotope, i can probably tell you what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks @Robotsushi, I'll put up now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a width for the columns.

Either use the option `masonry` and set its `columnWidth` to something that fits an image

```
masonry:{
    columnWidth:200
}
```

or give dimensions to the `.article` elements.

```
.article{
    width:200px;
}
```

This will help isotop to calculate the correct width for the columns ..

Comment: Thanks.  I added that width, I like the masonry effect I had going b4, but this does the trick for now!  Thanks!

Comment: @user576838 if you could post an image of the result you want it might be easier to suggest solutions.. you could remove the width and set ` layoutMode: 'fitRows'` for the isotope.

Comment: What i'm looking for is the default masonry behavior, where all the images are right next to each other.

Comment: Thanks man!  I'll try it later tonight when I'm home from work.  I appreciate it!